# Finding $x$ and $y$ from linearly dependent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The vectors $(1,x,3),(x+1,y,1)$ are linearly dependent. Find $x$ and $y$.

I searched and I found methods using Gaussian elimination but I didn't understand it.

Comment: **Two** vectors are linearly dependent iff they are scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: @user296602 so the answer is x=(-2/3) y=(-2/9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use the statement by user296602: two vectors are linearly dependent if and only if they are scalar multiples of each other (it is important that it be two vectors).

Let $v:=(1,x,3)$ and $u:=(x+1,y,1)$. Since $v$ and $u$ are linearly dependent by assumption, we have $v=cu$ for some constant $c$. Hence, $$(1,x,3)=(c(x+1),cy,c)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you know what is a cross product, then you should know that two vectors in three dimensional space are linearly dependent if and only if their cross product is null. Compute that cross product and write it being zero. This will give you a linear system of equations in x and y which you must solve.